# Как объединить транзакции ejb и spring

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, transaction, ejb

Есть спринговый бин в который инжекнуто несколько ejb бинов, каждый ejb бин выполняет свою бизнес логику и помечен внутри @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED) из javax.ejb соответственно.

Как в спринговом бине объединить все ejb бины в один метод под одной спринговой транзакцией? И будет ли это работать как распределённая транзакция (если отвалится транзакция какого то ejb-бина, то транзакция в спринговом бине так же свалится)?